# Hexagon images odd/even CSS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, css-selectors

So i have a hexagonal image and when i do ng-repeat i want the result to be as follows.

[image: hexa1]

The width of the container has to be 448px and the images need to be responsive.
This is what i have tried.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/adeel_s/pen/ZprPdE?editors=1100)

HTML

```
<div class="hexagons">
    <img src="images/hexagon5.png" alt="">
    <img src="images/hexagon6.png" alt="">
    <img src="images/hexagon5.png" alt="">
    <img src="images/hexagon6.png" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hexagons {
  max-width: 448px;
  height: 800px;
  position: relative;
}
.hexagons img:nth-child(even) {
  position: relative;
  top: -115px;
  left: 193px;
}
.hexagons img:nth-child(odd) {
  position: relative;
}
```

The result:

[image: Result]

Can someone please guide me through this.

Comment: http://csshexagon.com/ may come in handy :)

Comment: Can you provide a working example (not a screenshot...)?

Comment: @kolboc i am not looking for how to make a hexagon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by simply offsetting each even elements by half the height of the hexagon, example:

HTML

```
<div class="hexagons">
  <div class="hex"></div>
  <div class="hex"></div>
  <div class="hex"></div>
  <div class="hex"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hexagons {
  width: 300px;
}

.hex {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

.hex:nth-child(2n) { /* .hex:nth-child(even) works too! */
  position: relative;
  top: 50px; /* half of 100px */
}
```

Live example:
http://codepen.io/veksen/pen/GjYKBJ

Your pen corrected: http://codepen.io/veksen/pen/QKkLJg?editors=1100

Note that since images are block elements, I had to set them as blocks, and float them. The container has to be wide enough to accomodate two images (which are 256px wide). The even hexagons also needed to be shifted to the left.

Updated for responsive: http://codepen.io/veksen/pen/XjxWJo?editors=1100

Play with the percentages a bit, but you get the idea!

Comment: Hi thx for reply. i want the container width to be 448px and the images to be responsive. If i understand correctly you can do width 100% and height: auto to achieve that but when i do that i brake the whole thing.

Comment: I'll update my answer, but make sure you update your question to reflect that requirement, nothing is quite the same when you work with responsive ;)

Comment: Updated for responsiveness.

Comment: If this answers your question, make sure you be a good SO citizen, upvote and accept it :)